# Python constraint all variables x >= 0

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, gurobi

I have a distance matrix D for which I make the decision variables `x[i,j,k]` the following way:

```
    varsGurobi = [(i,j,k) for i in range(len(D)) for j in range(len(D[i])) for k in range(len(D[i][j])) if D[i][j]]

    x=model.addVars(varsGurobi, vtype=gp.GRB.INTEGER)
```

How can I add a lower bound of x or a constraint that x (I, j, k) should be equal or bigger than 0?

Currently I am doing it this way but it is very time consuming since the distance matrix is large:

```
[model.addConstr(x[i,j,k] >= 0) for i in range(len(D)) for j in range(len(D[i])) for k in range(len(D[i][j]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the Lower Bound when declaring the variable by using the `lb` keyword.  Reference:

https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/py_model_addvars.html

It is equivalent to what you are doing now, maybe a little faster to construct.

Slightly worrisome if you are creating an integer matrix that is so large that it is "time consuming" to construct...might be quite a haul to solve it, based on the rest of your model...

Comment: The default lower bound for variables is zero.